# Calculate the following Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin(\pi*x)|}{\lfloor x \rfloor} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

So I have to calculate the following Integral:
$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin(\pi*x)|} {\lfloor x \rfloor} dx$

I know how to calculate improper Integrals, but I really do have a problem with the $\lfloor x \rfloor$ (everytime it comes to any analysis excercise i can't solve it) even though i have read it's definition a lot of times and as far as i understand it it would be the greatest integer less than or equal to x. I also have a problem with he absolute value when it comes  to integrals.

I would like to add up here my part of the solution but in this case i really am stuck and have no clue what to do. Therefore i would really be greatful for any sort of help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The integrand function is not defined on the interval $(0, + \infty)$. If $0 < x < 1$ you have $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: I see but that's exactly how it is given in the excercise

Comment: I would say "the integral is not defined", and conclude the exercize in this way.

Comment: What's $\Huge *$ ?.

Answer (score 3):

I will solve the integral
$$\int_1^{+ \infty} \frac{|\sin ( \pi x)|}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \mathrm d x$$
since for $0 < x < 1$ you have something divided by zero.

Split the integral into a series:
$$\int_1^{+ \infty} \frac{|\sin ( \pi x)|}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \mathrm d x = 
\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \int_n^{n+1} \frac{|\sin ( \pi x)|}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \mathrm d x
$$
In the interval $(n,n+1)$ the floor function is constant and evaluates $n$.

Moreover $|\sin ( \pi x)|$ is a periodic function with period $1$. In particular
$$\int_n^{n+1} |\sin ( \pi x)| \mathrm d x = \int_0^1 |\sin ( \pi x)| \mathrm d x = C$$
where $C$ is a positive constant I don't want to compute.

Hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \int_n^{n+1} \frac{|\sin ( \pi x)|}{\lfloor x \rfloor} \mathrm d x=
\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \int_n^{n+1} \frac{|\sin ( \pi x)|}{n} \mathrm d x= 
\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty}  \frac{C}{n} = + \infty
$$
So the integral is divergent.

Comment: ..Bravo A.! :-)

Comment: @Joe <3 this was easy...

Comment: $\displaystyle +1$. Good job. I like your "I don't want to compute" statement.